# Scan port result add in the DataGridView. PowerShell

Tags: powershell, winforms, datagrid, port, tcpclient

Need a consultation which method will be better to apply in the script.
My Issue is next: I write Windows Form on PoSh. One of the function is the scanning port for available. I try two methods:

1. **Test-NetConnection**
2. **System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient**.

The result should be input in **DataGridView** area with 3 columns: **Remote Address, Remote Port, Status(Connected).**
If the port opened in **Test-Connection** method no any problem. All working excellent.
In the method **System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient** for opened port i don't recieve **Status(Connected)**.
It is the first problem.

If port is closed, in **Test-Connection** method all script are freezing when ping steps is begin. Have to forcibly terminate the PoSh.
In method **System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient** save the problem for opened port (don't recieve Status(Connected) port).

So, i interesting which method better to use, and how to resolve occur problems?

The part of code were troubles occur below:

```
$Portlist = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
<#------======== DataGrid Result Port Scan ========------#>
$DataGridResultScan = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$DataGridResultScan.Location = '225,30'
$DataGridResultScan.Size = '400,130'
$DataGridResultScan.AutoSize = $true
$DataGridResultScan.AutoSizeColumnsMode = 'AllCells'
$DataGridResultScan.AutoSizeRowsMode = 'AllCells'
$CommonForm.Controls.Add($DataGridResultScan)
<#------======== DataGrid Result Port Scan ========------#>
<#------======== Button Port Scan ========------#>
$ButtonPortScan = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$ButtonPortScan.Location = '400, 5'
$ButtonPortScan.Text = 'Check'
$ButtonPortScan.AutoSize = $true
$ButtonPortScan.add_Click({
                if (($ListboxListeServers.SelectedItem -ne $null) -and ($TextBoxPortScan.Text -eq '')){                
                    $SelectedServer = $ListboxListeServers.SelectedItem.ToString()
                    foreach ($NetworkPort in $NetworkPorts){
                             $listBoxResultScan.BeginUpdate()
                             $Result = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient
                             $Result.Connect($SelectedServer,$NetworkPort)
                             $ScanPortStatus = "Имя хоста:"+ " "+ $SelectedServer + $t +"Адрес :" + " "+([System.Net.DNS]::GetHostAddresses($SelectedServer)).IpAddressToString +  $t + "Порт :" + " " + $NetworkPort + $t + "Статус :" + " " + $Result.Client.Connected
                             $listBoxResultScan.Items.Add($ScanPortStatus)
                             $listBoxResultScan.EndUpdate()
                             Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
                     }
                 }
                 elseif (($ListboxListeServers.SelectedItem -ne '') -and ($TextBoxPortScan.Text -ne '')){
                        $SelectedServer = $ListboxListeServers.SelectedItem
                        $SelectedPorts = $TextBoxPortScan.Text -split ','
                        foreach ($SelectedPort in $SelectedPorts){
**<#---- Here is the first Method ----#>**
                        #$Portlist.AddRange(@(Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $SelectedServer -Port $SelectedPort -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | select ComputerName,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,TcpTestSucceeded))
**<#---- Here is the Second Method ----#>**
                                $Portlist.AddRange(@(New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient($SelectedServer, $SelectedPort) | select @{Label = 'Remote Address';E={$_.Client.RemoteEndPoint.Address}}, @{Label = 'Remote Port';Expression = {$_.Client.RemoteEndPoint.Port}},@{Label = 'Connected';E = {$_.Client.Connected}}))
                                $DataGridResultScan.DataSource = $null
                                $DataGridResultScan.DataSource = $Portlist
                                Start-Sleep -Seconds 1                            
                         }
                 }
})
$CommonForm.Controls.Add($ButtonPortScan)
<#------======== Button Port Scan ========------#>
```

Comment: When you ping a device and no response there is normally a timeout which is causing your app to hang.  I usually ping without waiting for results.  The results of a Ping are stored in an ARP table.  So I read result from the ARP instead of from the ping.  I sually add a few seconds wait between sending ping and reading ARP.  You can see the ARP table using Get-NetNeighbor.  Then comparing the sent IP against the ARP will give the IP found and not found. PING is ARP Protocol where there is a ARP Request and an ARP Response.

Comment: @jdweng, I don't understand, how can this be organized syntactically? Can you show example for my code?

Comment: Do pings first.  Then fill DGV from ARP table.  You have an add.Click( { CODE  }).  The CODE can be anything.

Comment: @jdweng The CODE can be anything - I understand it. But i don't understand how to do that the commandlet Test-netConnection do first ping and after scan port.

Comment: Try something like this : Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $SelectedServer -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | out-Null;
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5;

$arpResults = Get-NetNeighbor | Where-Object {$_.IPAddress -eq $SelectedServer }
if($arpResults -ne $null)
{
   $results = $arpResults | select-object -Property IPAddress, State;
   $results | Format-List;
}
else
{
   Write-Host "Server" $SelectedServer "Failed";
}